# unable to migrate data post cloning from GIT to server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, postgresql

Context: I am trying to set up my code from git on the server. 
I have successfully uploaded to git and then cloned from git.Howerver after that, I am unable to migrate my database

```
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column ratings.status does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  "ratings".* FROM "ratings" WHERE "ratings"."status"
```

here is my database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: postgres
  password: My_Pasword
  host: localhost

development:
  <<: *default
  database: healthworld_development
```

I have tried creating a new db and dropping it.

```
rake db:drop db:create db:migrate
```

I have also tried to add the column suggested in error

```
rails generate migration addStatustoRatings Status:string
```

here is my schema file

```
  create_table "ratings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "location_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.date     "use_date"
    t.string   "reason" 
    t.decimal  "overall_experience", default: "0.0"
    t.decimal  "doctor_care",        default: "0.0"
    t.decimal  "nursing_care",       default: "0.0"
    t.decimal  "cleanliness",        default: "0.0"
    t.decimal  "food_services",      default: "0.0"
    t.string   "recommend"
    t.text     "comment"
    t.datetime "created_at",                         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                         null: false
    t.decimal  "customer_service",   default: "0.0"
    t.string   "get_ins"
    t.decimal  "cost_satisfaction",  default: "0.0"
    t.decimal  "claims_process",     default: "0.0"
    t.integer  "status",             default: 0
    t.index ["location_id"], name: "index_ratings_on_location_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_ratings_on_user_id", using: :btree
```

20200207080641_add_status_to_ratings.rb

```
class AddStatusToRatings < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :ratings, :status, :integer, default: 0
  end
end
```

I think I missed something. thanks in advance

Comment: Don't you think that the migration is extremely relevant here? Please add it and provide as much information as you can about the schema before the migration is run. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: yes, I did run the migration indicated by the error, I added status to my ratings table

Comment: Thats good and all. But please add the relevant code to the question when asked. I'm actually trying to help you here but we need to actually see the full picture to have any chance at it. We can't just look at a crystal ball and see what you messed up.

Comment: Can you add your migration that you added for status column, It will help to understand issue properly.

Comment: sorry my bad, I am new to RoR development. I have edited my question and added the schema file to suffice my issue solving. thanks

Comment: @DipakGupta I have added my migration.it should help

Comment: i just need to get my server up and running. what other options do i have?

Comment: Is `add_status_to_ratings.rb` really the file name? It should be postfixed with a timestamp that ensures that your migrations run in the correct order. I'm guessing this is not the migration that raises the error either since `add_column` creates `ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN new_column_name data_type;`. It does not create a `SELECT` query.

Comment: on doing further research, I think it may be a conflict between rails version(5.0) and psql (PostgreSQL 10.10) version. because this error didn't occur the first time made my code live